# Angular based backend and integration of Firebase Admin sdk

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, angular6

I am using angular firebase in my angular firebase backend panel that I am creating for my mobile apps. However I require to send push notification to devices as admin.

I tried adding firebase-admin however its breaking entire backend with weird errors like . List is quite long

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../package' in 'xxxx/backend/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
```

What exactly is the issue, why is not compatible with angular and how can I use admin sdk to send push notifications

Comment: Actually what you're describing sounds like "frontend" app just used for administrative tasks. Usually what runs in the client is called the "frontend" and what runs on server is called "backend."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Firebase admin is not meant to be run in the browser. Are you including it into a NodeJS Web Server or into your Angular Application?

Comment: Well, I am creating an angular application that will act as Backend Admin Panel. However if we cant' then how can I send notifications to EnD users

Comment: Please take more time to read the responses carefully. Where are you trying to execute firebase admin? In the browser or server? 

You can't import (afaik) Firebase Admin into Angular / client.